# Kafka - how to get delete messages which were delete due to expiry

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way to retrieve deleted messages from Kafka? especially those messages which were deleted due to expiry time.

I am looking for a use case when our consumer is down or maybe super busy processing other messages and didn't get a chance to reach those messages.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get data that's been deleted, no.

Run a Kafka connector that has more uptime and less lag than your other consumers to write to somewhere more permanent and query that instead of Kafka, or increase the retention time, if you're frequently having this situation